# How to Get a data from a table and insert another table in YII form

Tags: yii

I am newbe in YII. Apologies for simple and stupid question.

I messed up my system. In that Case I need your help to clear the concept :: my question is :::

How to Get a data from a table and insert another table in YII form ::::
means---> I want to get data and view in form field --> how can I do that ??

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Generate a model using gii. It will do all what you need and hopefully you can get the code for that.

```
localhost:2010/index.php?r=gii
```

Use Above changing your host and port to see Gii.

You have to Enable Gii in the Config file before doing this

Comment: I have created two model A & B. Now I want to pick a table data from B and insert to in table A. please help

Answer (score 0):

```
$modelA = ModelA:;model()->find('somecondition');

$modelB= new ModelB();

$modelB->attribute1 = $modelA->attribute1;
$modelB->attribute2 = $modelA->attribute2;
$modelB->attribute3 = $modelA->attribute3;
$modelB->attribute4 = $modelA->attribute4;
$modelB->attribute5 = $modelA->attribute5;
$modelB->save();
```

Try this..

Comment: what about the form field.. please let me know your form field by placing $modelA = ModelA:;model()->find('somecondition');